# AppleTalk adapters to bridge LocalTalk to Ethernet?

Tags: apple-macintosh, apple-iigs, network, appletalk

What AppleTalk adapters can bridge LocalTalk to Ethernet? There are some adapter that allow LocalTalk printers to show up on ethernet, but I want to allow computers to talk. My IIgs has LocalTalk but all my Macs have only Ethernet. I have an old adapter, but the IIgs disappears from the Ethernet network after a few minutes.

Comment: I used an AsanteTalk about a decade and a bit ago to connect a ethernet Mac running the classic OS to a then already superannuated AppleTalk Mac; unfortunately I have absolutely no recollection whether that made the AppleTalk Mac look exactly like a regular ethernet device, or whether there was some special handling on the ethernet Mac that would limit this solution to OS 9 and below, whether by a specific driver or otherwise. Looking now, it's advertised only for AppleTalk printer usage, though the user manual https://www.manualslib.com/manual/210498/Asante-Asantetalk.html is broader.

Comment: Specifically, if memory serves: I was able to transfer files between a clamshell iBook and an SE/30. But this is a really hazy recollection. Prior to reading this question, I had no memory of this having happened at all.

Comment: AppleTalk protocol is no longer supported; I believe MacOS 10.5 is the latest operating system version with AppleTalk capability, whether through LocalTalk/Phonenet media or Ethernet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is a [LocalTalk to Ethernet bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LocalTalk-to-Ethernet_bridge).

It's possible to use a computer for this but in general the most reliable and easiest path is to use a device made for this purpose.

For example, I have a Shiva FastPath device that has a LocalTalk port and an Ethernet port.  It will then transfer AppleTalk and IP traffic between them.  If you only want AppleTalk to flow but not other protocols like TCP/IP that can be done as well, different products have different features and many products (like the FastPath) are configurable to selectively enable/disable things.

Comment: I'll have to look into the more advanced devices like the Shiva FastPath, I have a simple Farallon LocalTalk to Ethernet adapter that has no options.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using a Focus EtherLAN print box since many years for exactly that purpose with great success. It's small, reasonably fast, doesn't eat much power and it isn't restricted to only handle printers.

Sometimes, the box would simply hang but a power cycle fixes this always. After I put the box from a normal switch port on it's own spare AppleTalk-only interface on a Cisco Router, the problems were gone. Seems it can't handle too much broadcast traffic well.